# How to disable vscode's errorlens extension warning?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to disable errorlens's waring [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yutzq.png)

I tried like this

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    // "editorError.border": "#fff0",
    // "editorError.foreground": "#fff0",
    "editorWarning.border": "#fff0",
    "editorWarning.foreground": "#fff0",
    "editorWarning.background": "#fff0",
    "errorLens.warningBackground": "#fff0",
    "errorLens.warningForeground": "#fff0"
    // ...
  }
```

but it dooesn't work...

How to disable vscode's errorlens extension warning?

Answer (score 1):

Please open the command pallet in VS Code and type `errorLens.toggleWarning`.

Source: [Error lens Extension in VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens)